# Data Analyst doing multiple roles

Tags: salary

I am working in a tech startup (post product market fit) of around 100 employees as a 'Product Manager' but my role is more of a data analyst/engineer. I built the BI infrastructure and reporting of the company (implementing BI tools, coding ETL pipelines, and getting the teams in a position where they can self-serve).

While this role is fun and challenging, I often feel the need of a wider team to deal with BI Data, as opposed to having me do it all - I get paid junior analyst level.

I recently mentioned my interest in leaving and they quickly offered a 10% pay rise, while expecting me to take on more responsibilities.

What is the best way of requesting more resources and a pay level consistent to that of my responsibilities and value add? Similar roles outside of our firm pays 50% more than what I get, but they tend to require more experienced individuals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: I recommend you apply for those roles. Regardless of whether you'd take them. If you get offered those jobs then you know what you're worth and what your options are. If you don't, then that's also useful information you can use to inform your decisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the payout should not depend on experience level or designation. It should be focused on what value you add to the organization and how your skillset is being utilized.

Other than that, the required workforce for any work / work area usually depends on the target deadline. For example, if you have six month to complete a task, probably you can do that on your own. But if you have to get that job done in one or two months, you'd need help (in form of maybe five-six more members working in a team).

Do your homework, then talk to your manager about

- Your contributions and value-add, and what is the appropriate remuneration for all the accomplishments by you.
- The tasks in pipeline and the target deadlines for them.

This will show that you know what you're doing and your planning capabilities. Win-Win.

Answer (score 1):

> Similar roles outside of our firm pays 50% more than what I get, but they tend to require more experienced individuals.

Does the "fun and challenge" of your current position, outweigh being paid 50% more for what you?  If not, then I would encourage you to just go ahead and apply for these similar roles.  As of this writing (summer 2021), there is an acute shortage of experienced developers.  *Acute*.  I don't have numbers, but anecdotally, all I can say is, *wow* is there ever a run on senior developers right now.

And experience isn't just measured in years -- having built out a complete BI stack that your company relies on, is no mean feat.

(Of course, if you do get an offer, they will probably not offer 50% more, based on your years-on-resume and by basing their offer on what you're currently making, plus a bump; but, as addressed by [another question on this site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/171678/how-do-you-get-a-big-salary-increase-in-your-career-if-every-job-just-offers-10/171687#171687), you don't strictly have to tell them what you're currently making, just what you'd be willing to leave your current position for.)

Comment: Agree completely with this, but one caveat -- If you think you can likely get 50% more, do NOT tell future companies what salary you're making!! Simply say "I'm not able to disclose my current salary, but based on my research I'm looking for X amount". I've been in this exact situation and literally got a 50% increased offer by refusing to say my current salary.

Answer (score 0):

**Continue showing your value to the company**

The company gave a raise and a promotion when you mentioned you might want to leave.

> Similar roles outside of our firm pays 50% more than what I get, but they tend to require more experienced individuals.

And this is why the raise was 10%.  Continue to do well in this role and you'll be able to get another raise next year.  Look at the going salary for your position each year, decide if it's worth it to go for a raise or get a new job.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old workplace adage, "the fastest way to a pay raise is to find a new job". Take that with a grain of salt. Build up your skills, learn all you can in company, pivot around the company, and build up your worth. If you spend the time to do that successfully you will be writing your own checks.

Answer (score -2):

The extremely simple answer here is

- Get much more money.  Ask for it *today*.
- If you don't get it the day you ask for it, then the following day start aggressively job seeking.

It's that simple.

This question comes up on here a lot.  I always find the question really surprising:

> "I'm in a job where I am working incredibly hard and doing a huge amount of stuff."

The answer is just so simple:

> "Man, I wish I was you!  **Get a fatass raise right now**."

---

Footnote.  If you are struggling with the language for how to ask for a raise, send the following email to your immediate boss and big boss

> Hi guys. Thanks again for the incredible job here. Presently I'm doing four roles, each of which is way beyond my current pay scale. Based on this I'd need my salary to be $xxx,000 *{exact figure}* from the first of next month. Please note that this would still be saving the company, at the minimum, two other full time staff. Could you give me your thoughts on this and let me know this week?

Just to repeat myself the question literally asks,

> What is the best way of requesting more resources and a pay level consistent to that of my responsibilities and value add

the email wording is

> I'd need my salary to be $xxx,000 *{exact figure}* from the first of next month.

plus **add some polite buffer** on each side of that phrase.

Always be extremely polite.

Keep it *short*.

Note - *never, ever* give rationales or reasons when you state you want a higher salary. The person on the other side of the negotiation is a professional. They will demolish your reasoning in two words.

For example, if someone told me

> Similar roles outside of our firm pays 50% more than what I get

I'd just chuckle, respond with 13 words ("I just reviewed the market and you're making far more than the market").  Then to annoy you I'd add 16 more words ("Actually the provisional raise you just received, I can see no reason for. We'll review that.") Then I'd ask you to please get back to work.

The people who manage for companies, are ****s. Their only role in life is to keep your pay down - nothing else.

**If you try to give "reasons" to a professional negotiator on the other side, they'll unfortunately just destroy the negotiation right there.**

1. state the money you want
2. if you don't get it, immediately job search

Comment: Very aggressive approach and an overly negative view of Management. Not every company and every manager are the same. Making demands that sound like threats is usually not a good idea. Your boss and his/her boss are not (usually) your enemies.

Comment: hi @obe - I'm all for using polite language.  I emphasize this in the answer.  but the undeniable facts are (1) the op needs a (very substantial) raise.  and (2) if the answer is "no" ........ OP has to leave.  these are two concrete, unbendable, unchangeable facts, unfortunately.  (and BTW regarding this particular company: the fact that they gave OP a comic small raise for what OP is doing, is not a good sign.)

Comment: whether or not the OP should get a raise depends on various factors. and i'm not against asking for $XXX and not settling for less. but i don't think the way to go about it is with phrasing like "i need to get" / "i expect to get", and certainly not in an email (even with polite buffer). i also don't see a problem with presenting the rationale, nor do i think that the other side would necessarily demolish it...